# Get a certain text in a string - flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter

I have a list of strings i want to pass to the next screen based on which item is selected. However in the next screen how do i extract only the usernames in the string which is text 'user1' and text 'user2'

First screen's code that passed the data to second screen:

```
List<String> data = [
    "user1 @ 186.53",
    "user2 @ 23.432",
  ];
...
onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => SecondScreen(text: '${items[index]}'),

                   ),
                ),
```

Second screen's code that retrieve the data:

```
final String text;

SecondScreen({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
```

So the text contained when retrieved is:

```
user1 @ 186.53
```

how do i only extract the text 'user1' in the string above?

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it if `@` is present in all string values.

```
String val = 'user1 @ 186.53';

List user = val.split('@');
print(user[0]);  // output is user1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String rawData = "user1 @ 186.53";
String result = rawData.split(" ")[0];
```

This code separates the first item in rawData separated by a space and puts it in result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly declare:
`List split(Pattern pattern) {}`  outside the class,Now-

`String data="user1 @ 186.53";`

`String edata= data.split(" ").elementAt(0);`

`print(edata);`

`output: user1`